# Unable to display the employees whose salary is grater than 1300

Tags: oracle

I'm using Oracle DB. The question is

*Select all employee who jobs are either CLERK or SALESMAN and have salary greater than 1300.*.

Hence my answer is

```
select ENAME from EMP where JOB='CLERK' OR JOB='SALESMAN' AND SAL>1300;
```

The problem here is even though I have mentioned as salary to be greater than 1300, it is listing employee names with salary 800/1100 etc. What is wrong with my query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [list condition precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/About-SQL-Conditions.html#GUID-65B103FE-C00C-46A3-8173-A731DBF62C80) form high to low. That shows that `AND` is evaluated before `OR`. With no parentheses your query:

```
select ENAME from EMP where JOB='CLERK' OR JOB='SALESMAN' AND SAL>1300;
```

is evaluated as

```
select ENAME from EMP where JOB='CLERK' OR (JOB='SALESMAN' AND SAL>1300);
```

so the 1300 limit is only applied to salesmen, and you will see clerks with any salary. To change that default implied precedence you need to supply parentheses, as @user7294900 showed:

```
select ENAME from EMP where (JOB='CLERK' OR JOB='SALESMAN') AND SAL>1300;
```

You could also use an `IN()` condition here:

```
select ENAME from EMP where JOB IN ('CLERK', 'SALESMAN') AND SAL>1300;
```

Answer (score 2):

Add parentheses between AND conditions

```
select ENAME from EMP where (JOB='CLERK' OR JOB='SALESMAN') AND SAL>1300;
```